# Civil Union Partner with Family Permit approved travelling with EEA member - Customs Queue

Tags: customs-and-immigration, eu, family

My Family Member permit was approved - Civil Union Partnership with separate Surnames.  Can I join my partner at the EU Customs queue when entering the UK?

Comment: What country are you going to, and what country is your passport from?

Comment: We are going to UK and my Partner has an Italian passport. I am South African and is travelling on a Family Permit that clearly indicates that I am traveling with my Partner...thereafter we are going to Italy.

Answer (score 6):

No, but they can join you in your queue. 
EU passports can go through digital scanners, so when entering countries like the UK for example, the EU queue is to machines only, if your passport was from a different country and was not eligible to use in the machines then they would not open to let you through.

I have gone through non EU passport lines with friends before so we didn't get separated, and boarder control are fine with that, but it would not have worked the other way around.

Comment: There are still some 'EU passports' gates with humans at some EU airports, for those families traveling with small children, for those traveling with ID cards and so on. OP can likely use that line with his/her partner.

Comment: @Willeke That is true there are some with people, but if OP is not a member of the EU, and does not have an EU passport, they should not be in that line, and could be sent back to line up where their passport belongs.

Comment: At Schengen borders, family of Schengen and EU citizens are explicitly authorized by the Schengen Borders Code to use the EU/EEA/CH queue.  The situation is less clear in the UK, but I've used the EU queue there with a non-EU partner without much trouble.

Comment: @phoog, are you willing to write your own answer?

Comment: @Willeke I'm unlikely to have time today or over the weekend.

Comment: None other than Gayot Fow has said it's OK. See the linked suggested duplicate. Of course things may change after Brexit...